# How can I open terminal with GPIO input and run bash script and see the output in realtime?

Tags: python, bash, terminal, raspberry-pi3, gpio

Thank you for reading. I have this pi tft screen with tactile buttons connected to it.  When a button is held for two seconds, I´d like to open a terminal and run a bash script. The problem is that I need to view the output/progress of the script in realtime.

This python script, which monitors GPIO, works perfectly if a terminal is already open, then I can see the output.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import subprocess
def runboth():

subprocess.call(["/opt/script/test.sh"])

runboth_btn = Button(17, hold_time=2)
runboth_btn.when_held = runboth


pause()
```

But if the pythons script is run from boot for example, no terminal will open since I guess it is running in the background? How can I achieve that the script will also open a terminal ?

I have tried the following but without luck.

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import subprocess

def runboth():

    subprocess.call(["lxterminal", "--command=/opt/script/test.sh"])

    runboth_btn = Button(17, hold_time=2)
    runboth_btn.when_held = runboth


    pause()
```

I´m met with this error

```
root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/lxterminal --command=/opt/script/test.sh
Mar 24 23:24:42 raspberrypi sudo[1315]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 24 23:24:42 raspberrypi lxterminal[1319]: cannot open display: 0:0
```

Or if run from terminal

```
lxterminal:1404): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

This is the bash scripts I am currently using for test.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
echo "hello"
done
```

I run a Raspberry PI 3, Raspian OS with root privileges.

Again, thank you for reading and taking your time!

Comment: I'm curious how you run your script from boot? All these may not necessary if you run the script from boot correctly.

Comment: The errors with opening a terminal (`cannot open display`) are probably caused by the root user not being allowed to open a terminal on a display that is running as a standard user. You can solve this with `xauth`. But I'm not really sure that this is what you want to do.

Comment: @hcheung, I run it with a 'systemd service file'. Cron or rc.local doesnt work to run if from boot.

Comment: @matli, I'm happy to run it with a normal user if possible.. I guess the root is done automatically since the script requires sudo permission . I can try xauth... how does that work?

Comment: Have you try using `(sleep 10;python scriptname.py)&` by adding it to `/etc/rc.local`? This do not need sudo.

Comment: Alternatively to open lxterminal on boot up, go to `/home/pi/.config/autostart` (create these folders if they don't exist) and add `lxterminal` to the file. This will run as normal user. Remember to reboot for the setting after you done the setting.

Comment: @ hcheung, rc.local works in terms of that with the TOP command I can see the python script is active.. however no putput when button is pressed.. I still get the "(lxterminal:1126): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" if I run it from terminal..

Comment: If you want to go the xauth route, you could probably get started by checking answers to questions like this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication